# How to set relative configuration file for my name-password AP?

Tags: pi-3, linux, wpa, raspberry-pi-os

I would like to connect my RPi3 with wifi attached. I can scan all APs in my office using command "iwlist wlan0 scan". But I can't find IP address at response of ifconfig wlan0. I can connect to an AP using name/password at Windows. How can I connect to that AP and get IP address using DHCP.
I set my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
sudo wpa_supplicant /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

content of /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
update_config=1

network={
ssid="MiTAC-Wifi1"
key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
eap=PEAP
phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
identity="stan.huang"
password="rasp7890"
}
```

I doesn't work. How should I do with it?

Comment: Add `country=TW` as the third line in your supplicant config.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Raspberry Pi OS Buster?

Comment: GNU/Linux with kernel (4.19.57-V7+)

Comment: GNU/Linux are all Linux operating systems: Debian, Fedora, Suse, Slackware etc. They all behave different. Again: are you using GNU/Linux [Raspberry Pi OS Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/)?

Comment: My OS should be Raspberry Pi OS

Answer (score 1):

You are using old deprecated settings for WiFi. I don't know where do you get this. With **Raspberry Pi OS**, WiFi is working out of the box. You only have to use the right settings. I suggest you start over again with a fresh flashed [Raspberry Pi OS image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) of your choice. Then follow the official documentation for [Wireless connectivity in the Raspberry Pi Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/desktop.md) or [Setting up a wireless LAN via the command line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).